# Question about physical character of 4-tensors in Special Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Consider the following:

> Any candidate for a physical observable quantity in special relativity must to be expressed as a scalar quantity, constructed from tensorial quantities which describes the physical system and the observer by which the observable quantity is measuared.
>
> So, as an example of this idea and concept, the energy is written as:
>
> $$E = -p^{\mu}u_{\mu}$$
>
> Where, $p^{\mu}$, is the 4-momentum and $u_{\mu}$ is 4-velocity. So, $p^{\mu}$ is the tensor that describes the physical system and $u_{\mu}$ is the tensor which gives you the information of the observer.

I would like to know why Energy is written like that above,and then what is the exact relationship between the concept of "information of the observer", tetrad basis and projections.

Comment: Link to quote ?

Comment: Acctually,@Qmechanic, it's from a blackboard of a past course on relativity. There's no link.

Comment: @JackClerk: So edit your question to say what the source is, and credit the author properly. Don't just randomly cut and paste stuff from the internet without attribution. It's rude.

Comment: Your question talks about a tetrad basis and projections, but the quoted text doesn't say anything about those things. What makes you think there is some relationship? Don't expect us to guess your meaning.

Answer (score 1):

We can show $-p_\mu u^\mu =mc^2$, with $m$ the rest mass. Thus our result is the rest energy. For $3$-velocity $v$ we have $u^0=\gamma c,\,u^i = \gamma v^i$ so $u_\mu u^\mu = \gamma^2 (c^2 - v^2) = c^2$. Finally, $p_\mu=mu_\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a particle with 4-momentum $p^\mu$ and an observer with 4-velocity $u^\mu$,
 the "[relativistic] energy of that particle according to that observer" is
$$E=-p^\mu g_{\mu \nu} u^\nu,$$
using the metric and using the (-,+,+,+) signature convention.
In words, this [relativistic] energy is the [minus] time-component of the particle's 4-momentum.

In the frame of the observer, this can expressed in the observer's coordinates $(\hat t, \hat x)$ using
$$u^\nu=\hat t^\nu$$
and
$$p^\nu=mv^\nu=m(\cosh\theta\ \hat t^\nu+\sinh\theta\ \hat x^\nu)$$
[where $m$ is the rest-mass of the particle and $v^\nu$ is the 4-velocity of the particle, and $\theta$ is the rapidity of the particle in this frame]

by
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
E 
&=& -p^\mu g_{\mu \nu} u^\nu \\
&=& - m(\cosh\theta\ \hat t^\mu+\sinh\theta\ \hat x^\mu) \cdot \hat t^\nu \\
&=& - m(\cosh\theta)\ \hat t^\mu \cdot \hat t^\nu \\
&=& - m(\cosh\theta)\ (-1)\\
&=&  m(\cosh\theta)\\
&=&  m\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Restoring the factors of $c$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
E&=&  mc^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$